# How can I keep a Channel alive after an error?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I want to delete several queues on our RabbitMQ server and have some code that looks like this:

```
string[] queuesToDelete = new[] {
  "QueueThatExists1",
  "QueueThatDoesn'tExist", // this queue causes an error - which I expect
  "QueueThatExists2" };    // this queue also errors - which I don't expect

IConnectionFactory factory = ...
using (IModel = factory.CreateModel()) {
  foreach (string queue in queuesToDelete) {
    try {
      model.QueueDelete(queue);
      Console.WriteLine("Queue {0} deleted");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine("Queue {0} could not be deleted because {1}", queue, e);
    }
  }
}
```

However I get this as output:

> Queue QueueThatExists1 deleted
>   Queue QueueThatDoesn'tExist could not be deleted because Queue Not Found
>   Queue QueueThatExists2 could not be deleted because Already Closed

I have changed the code to look more like this (which works as I expect):

```
string[] queuesToDelete = new[] {
  "QueueThatExists1",
  "QueueThatDoesn'tExist", // this queue causes an error - which I expect
  "QueueThatExists2" };    // this queue also errors - which I don't expect

IConnectionFactory factory = ...
IModel model;
try {
  model = factory.CreateModel();
  foreach (string queue in queuesToDelete) {
    try {
      model.QueueDelete(queue);
      Console.WriteLine("Queue {0} deleted");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine("Queue {0} could not be deleted because {1}", queue, e);
      // reset the connection
      model.Dispose();
      model = factory.CreateModel();
    }
  } finally {
    if (model != null)
      model.Dispose();
  }
}
```

However this looks bad. I have removed a `using` statement and hand rolled the same thing with a `try - finally` block. It feels like I am fighting the API. **Question:** Is there a more elegant way of achieving the same result?

I notice that RabbitMQ for java has [lyra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19575837/2053848) and [autorecovery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26098966/2053848), but cannot find anything similar for C#.

Comment: JFYI: there are channel-level errors that closes channel and connection-level errors that forces all channels inside connection closed as well as connection itself. Your channel can't survive after such kind of errors. Sure, there are regular errors which doesn't lead to channel or connection closing. But it also depends on client library implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Check out project [EasyNetQ](http://easynetq.com/).

EasyNetQ implement subscriber reconnection ([EasyNetQ doc](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Quick-Start)).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a try/catch I recommend checking if that you're interested in exists.  You can do this with the API. Here is our method to do that:

```
  private bool DoesSomethingExist(string something, string queueOrExchange)
    {
        var connectionInfo = GetRabbitConnectionInfo();
        var url = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}", connectionInfo.APIUrl, queueOrExchange, connectionInfo.VirtualHostName, something);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", connectionInfo.UserName, connectionInfo.Password));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var content = response.Content;
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Unhandled API response code of {0}, content: {1}", response.StatusCode, content));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good idea, my criticism is that I would also have to add a `IsQueueLocked()` to check that the queue is not locked before deleting, and `DoIHaveDeletingPermissions()`, and ... plus everything that comes up in the future.